# How to make a Windows Runtime Page refresh when it goes to foreground?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make a [Windows Runtime Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx) refresh/reload every time it goes to foreground. I have tried to add a handler to the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event, but the Loaded event is only fired when the page is first loaded, which unlike the DOMContentLoaded event of HTML. What is the proper way to do so?

Thanks.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;

        this.Loaded += (s, e) => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Loaded at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            // Code that should be executed when the page goes to the foreground each time
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Looks like this is a valid question, it's a fairly simple scenario on Windows Runtime.

Comment: I think it is a valid question asking about the Loaded event of Windows Runtime Page and how a developer can refresh the content of a Windows Runtime Page every time it is shown to the screen (foreground). I have added a simple sample of the event handler and clarified that the expected behaviour would be similar to how DOMContentLoaded of HTML works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnNavigatedTo` method (as documented on the MSDN page you've put in your question) will be called every time a Page is navigated to.

You can use the `NavigationEventArgs` to determine what kind of navigation took place and handle this appropriately. In your case you would add code to refresh your page's content.

As Romasz points out, this will not help you in WinRT XAML stack when your app is resumed as the page doesn't get a call to `OnNavigatedTo` in that case.

For that you'd have to detect the application resume in your app and send a message to your page (or it's data source/View Model) to refresh.

Be aware of the app resume/suspend guidelines however ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx)).

Comment: That's not true in Runtime - *OnNavigatedTo* is not called when the app is resumed - [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx). When Navigated - yes, but not every time the page is shown.

Comment: I'm still mainly working on the Silverlight stack. Looks like that's a pretty major gotcha in transferring.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestion. It appears that I have to override the [Application.OnActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated) method and put the logic inside. However, I wish to keep the logic of the page in the same Page class (like handling HTML's DOMContentLoaded event). Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, in Application.OnActivated find the current Page in the Frame and call a method on it that contains your logic.

Comment: I thought that Application.OnActivated is always called, even when the user launches the app normally. That is however incorrect. Only [Application.OnLaunched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched) is called. I have added the following code at the end of OnLaunched, which calls a method of my page to refresh content:
    if (rootFrame.Content.GetType() == typeof(MainPage)) {
        await ((MainPage)rootFrame.Content).RefreshContent();
    }